# Detect Speed of Swipe with jQuery Mobile swiperight

Tags: jquery, mobile, swipe

I'm using jQuery Mobile and I want to detect the speed of a swipe to create a 'flick' effect with a carousel.

Is there a way to determine the speed of a swipe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm actually working on a mod of another script at the moment. I'll update here once I have it figured out.